# Mixer Client interface Beam object not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

im fetching data from the microsoft's mixer api to display channels details like viewers and followers.

i have tried using their online tutorial on their website but its giving me an error which is saying beam is not a constructor. 
here is their tutorial
https://dev.mixer.com/tutorials/rest.html

here is my code

```
 'use strict';
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  const path = require("path");
  const Beam = require('beam-client-node');
  const ejs = require("ejs");
  const beam = new Beam();

  //const channelName = process.argv[2];

  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

  app.get('/channel', (req, res) => {
     return beam.request('GET', 'channels/PootsTheCat').then(res => {
            const viewers = res.body.viewersTotal;
            console.log(`You have ${viewers} total viewers...`);
        });

    res.render('home');
  });



   app.listen(3000);
   console.log('Running on port 3000...');
```

here is the error

```
     TypeError: Beam is not a function<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at app.get 
     (C:\Users\Len\Documents\mixer\app.js:20:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at 
     Layer.handle [as handle_req
```

Answer (score 1):

Some changes were made to `beam-client-node` recently that will require some edits to your code. Updates were made to the tutorial but I'll also describe them here.

This line:
`const Beam = require('beam-client-node');`

Imports the entire Beam Module and its classes into the variable `Beam` as an object. Once imported you need to refer to properties of this object to obtain the various classes required.

In this case you're after the `Client` class that's a property on 'Beam'. From the tutorial there is this line which will get you an instantiated mixer client:

`const client = new Mixer.Client(new Mixer.DefaultRequestRunner());`

Once you have this you can then use .request:
`client.request('GET'....`